# Simplex noise range too small

Tags: c++, simplex-noise

I'm using the following implementation of simplex noise (Appendix B):
https://www.csee.umbc.edu/~olano/s2002c36/ch02.pdf

This was written by Ken Perlin himself.

The code in the PDF is written in JAVA but I've translated it to C++. Here is my code (you can also run it on [C++ Shell](http://cpp.sh/8jf5)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

int i,j,k, A[3] = {0,0,0};
float u,v,w;

int T[8] = {0x15,0x38,0x32,0x2c,0x0d,0x13,0x07,0x2a};
int b(int N, int B) { return N>>B & 1; }
int b(int i, int j, int k, int B) { return T[b(i,B)<<2 | b(j,B)<<1 | b(k,B)]; }

int shuffle(int i, int j, int k) {
    return b(i,j,k,0) + b(j,k,i,1) + b(k,i,j,2) + b(i,j,k,3) +
    b(j,k,i,4) + b(k,i,j,5) + b(i,j,k,6) + b(j,k,i,7) ;
}

float K(int a) {
    float s = (A[0]+A[1]+A[2])/6.;
    float x = u-A[0]+s, y = v-A[1]+s, z = w-A[2]+s, t = .6-x*x-y*y-z*z;
    int h = shuffle(i+A[0],j+A[1],k+A[2]);
    A[a]++;
    if (t < 0)
    return 0;
    int b5 = h>>5 & 1, b4 = h>>4 & 1, b3 = h>>3 & 1, b2= h>>2 & 1, b = h & 3;
    float p = b==1?x:b==2?y:z, q = b==1?y:b==2?z:x, r = b==1?z:b==2?x:y;
    p = (b5==b3 ? -p : p); q = (b5==b4 ? -q : q); r = (b5!=(b4^b3) ? -r : r);
    t *= t;
    return 8 * t * t * (p + (b==0 ? q+r : b2==0 ? q : r));
}

float noise(float x, float y, float z) {
    float s = (x+y+z)/3;
    i=(int)floorf(x+s); j=(int)floorf(y+s); k=(int)floorf(z+s);
    s = (i+j+k)/6.; u = x-i+s; v = y-j+s; w = z-k+s;
    A[0]=A[1]=A[2]=0;
    int hi = u>=w ? u>=v ? 0 : 1 : v>=w ? 1 : 2;
    int lo = u< w ? u< v ? 0 : 1 : v< w ? 1 : 2;
    return K(hi) + K(3-hi-lo) + K(lo) + K(0);
}

int main() {
    float scale = 0.0007f;
    float min = 1.0f;
    float max = -1.0f;
    for (int x = 0; x < 100000; x++) {
        float v = noise(x * scale, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        if (v > max) max = v;
        if (v < min) min = v;
    }
    printf("min = %f\r\n", min);
    printf("max = %f\r\n", max);
}
```

The problem is, calling the noise function is only giving me values near between -0.3 and 0.3.

I was expecting to get values between -1.0 and 1.0.

Is there a problem with this particular implementation?

Obs: I'm not normalizing the output and not calculating any additional octaves yet.

Comment: Please add the code here.

Comment: @Chipster are you sure? It's 35 lines of code.

Comment: Well, maybe you can reduce it a bit, create a [reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)?

Comment: I can't reduce any of those 35 lines. As to the reproducable example, I've added a link to C++ Shell.

Comment: Well, then I'd say just add them here then. If it can't be reduced, then it must be minimal. 35 doesn't sound like too much. Add them here. It will increase chances of an answer.

Comment: Alright, added the full code to the question and edited it a little bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution which I'm sure is not the correct way of doing this.

I changed this:

```
return 8 * t * t * (p + (b==0 ? q+r : b2==0 ? q : r));
```

To this:

```
return 26 * t * t * (p + (b==0 ? q+r : b2==0 ? q : r));
```

Now I'm getting a nice output.